# php open email client

Tags: php, html, mysql, email

I can use the following html to open the default email client 'on a new page'

```
<a onClick="javascript:window.open('mailto:mail@domain.com', 'Mail');event.preventDefault()" href="mailto:mail@domain.com">Send an e-mail</a>
```

as per ...

http://jsfiddle.net/cNUNP/

I have this php code below inside a while loop to display contact records from mysql db.

```
echo '<td><a href="mailto:'.$row["Email1"].'">'.$row["Email1"].'</a></td>';
```

The problem is that the php code opens email client in the same page!!

How can I modify php code to open email client in a new page as per html code?

Comment: I am using Firefox and I have tried  using target="_blank" with no success

Comment: i dont know which os you are using and which email client. in my case, I use win7+chrome+thunderbird it opens a new thunderbird-create-mail window even if i simply do `<a href='mailto:...' ..>` without using window.open and without using target=_blank. I think it depends on your system. And I think you cannot affect it.

Comment: update: thunderbird opens a new window each time i click on the link. If i click 3 times then i have 3 create-mail-windows open.

Comment: as @steven said you don't need any `onclick` just `href="mailto:..."`

Comment: I am using Win 7, my browser is Firefox and default email client is GMail.

Comment: I have just solved this using the following html/php in the loop...                ?>
<td>
<a onClick="javascript:window.open('mailto:<?php echo $row['Email1'];?>', 'Mail');event.preventDefault()" 
href="mailto:<?php echo $row['Email1'];?>"><?php echo $row['Email1'];?></a>
</td>
<?php

This fixes the problem but I'm sure there must be a better way ????

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved this using the following html/php in the loop...

```
?> 
<td> <a onClick="javascript:window.open('mailto:<?php echo $row['Email1'];?>', 'Mail');event.preventDefault()" href="mailto:<?php echo $row['Email1'];?>"><?php echo $row['Email1'];?></a> </td> 
<?php
```

This fixes the problem but I'm sure there must be a better way ????
Perhaps this may help some others.